# Herbrand-Ribet and Mazur-Wiles for function fields

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, finite-fields, l-functions, iwasawa-theory

Is there a version of Herbrand-Ribet or Mazur-Wiles (relating divisibility of class groups to special values of L-functions) for functions fields (over finite fields)?

Probably the proofs would have to be very different since we don't have a nice tool like modular forms to construct representations and extensions with nice properties out of (or do we?).

Answer (score 4):

*(I was hoping somebody else would answer this, because function fields are not really my area and I hoped I would learn something from the answer; but nobody seems to be biting, so...)*

Iwasawa theory over function fields definitely exists, and in many ways it's easier than number-field Iwasawa theory -- there are *more* nice tools available, such as the Grothendieck--Lefschetz trace formula, which aren't there in the number field setting.

For instance, [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.dmj/1077304443) is a paper of Goss and Sinnott from the 1980s which (among many other results) proves an analogue of Herbrand--Ribet for the class groups of function field extensions arising from Drinfeld modules.

Comment: Your link appears to behind warwick login wall. Is the paper "Class-groups of Functions Fields"?

Comment: @Asvin Yes, that's it. Link now fixed.